# Google Colab code blocks like feature in VScode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pip, google-colaboratory

I was wondering if there is some extension/framework/module to VScode/python that allows you to run code in blocks like on Google Colab, so you don't have to run time-consuming lines every time you change something not related in code. I'm pretty sure I saw something like that somewhere, but I don't know how it is named.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The extension is called `jupyter` by `Microsoft`. Install that and then Create the file with the extension `.ipynb` and you are good to go.